# Spring Boot Mongo: "$elemMatch needs an Object"

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, rest, mongodb-query

So I'm writing a search query, but got stuck with an error.\

Querying this query in Mongo Compass returns the correct results.

```json
{$or: 
  [
    {'title': {$regex : "aard", $options: 'i'} },
    {'tags': {$elemMatch: {$regex : "aard", $options: 'i'} } },
    {'categories': {$elemMatch: {$regex : "aard", $options: 'i'} } }
  ]
}
```

However querying with this query in spring boot throws an error:

> Query failed with error code 2 and error message '$elemMatch needs an Object'

```java
@Query("{$or: [" +
  "{'title': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'} }, " +
  "{'tags': {$elemMatch: {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'} } }," +
  "{'categories': {$elemMatch: {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'} } }" +
  "] }")
List<Product> search(String input);
```

Smaller example code with same result:

```java
@Query("{'categories': {$elemMatch: {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'} } }")
List<Product> findByCategory(String category);
```

Mongo Document Example:

```json
_id:1
supplier:DBRef(supplier, [object Object], undefined)
title:"Aardappels"
description:"Verse aardappels"
unitSize:"5KG"
categories:["Groente"]
tags:["Aardappels"]
price:14.99
salePrice:9.99
sale:true
amount:0
sold:0
_class: "nl.hva.ewaserver.models.Product"
```

It's weird, they both have the same query, but in spring boot I use parameters.
Which shouldn't be the problem, because I've also tested hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me while querying my **Mongodb** (While making a chat App)

Here is the code

```
 let isChat = await Chat.find({
        isGroupChat: false,
        $and: [{ users: { $elemMatch: LoginUserID } }, { users: { $elemMatch: userId } }]  
    }).populate('users', '-password')
```

The issue gets solved when I replaced $elemMatch with $eq.